# Arp Access-List Without An Interface

Tags: cisco, dhcp, arp, dhcp-snooping

I have dhcp snooping an arp inspection setup on my VLAN. I have a number of clients that need to be statically set on this VLAN but still plug into a DHCP access port on the VLAN. I have `ip dhcp Snooping` enable on the VLAN and `ip arp inspection` These clients need to move around the switch so they can't be statically set to a specific interface. I have made an arp access-list and it looks like so:

```
ip arp inspection filter TEST_EQUIP vlan 10    
arp access-list TEST_EQUIP
  permit ip host 192.168.1.104 mac host 0000.0000.0001
```

Is it possible to do this and not specify an interface so it can move around the VLAN to any port? Information found on Cisco's website does not stipulate it must be tied.

Comment: You can trust on the interface: `ip arp inspection trust`.

Comment: @RonMaupin but which interface? The switch port? Because I can't secure it to 1 Interface.

Comment: Yes, the switch interface.

Comment: @RonMaupin I need to have this device and 20+ others move around this switch. These ports aren't all for these devices. I can't just trust the interface.

Comment: Then you need to bind in the DHCP snooping database as the other question.

Comment: **ip dhcp snooping binding** _mac_address_ **vlan** _vlan_ID ip_address_ **interface** _ifname_ **expiry** _lease_in_seconds_

Comment: @RonMaupin But your setting the client to a specific interface. Which I can't do. It has to be able to move around to other interfaces

Comment: Then set an entry for each interface it may use. What you want is really not how it is designed. This is primarily for things like servers and printers that do not move.

Comment: Maybe you should use DHCP on those devices, but with DHCP reservations so that they get the same address every time. Then you do not need to introduce a security hole.

Comment: @RonMaupin The problem with that is in some cases the clients are in a location that sometimes power is lost at the upstream switch before it reaches the DHCP. So if the power is out for longer than the DHCP lease then it drops the address and we lose data on those devices. It's strange I know.